# How to match on all integers in a range in a total function?

Tags: idris, proof-of-correctness

Let's say we want to check the parity of an `Int`:

```
data Parity = Even | Odd
```

It would be pretty easy for `Nat`:

```
parity0: Nat -> Parity
parity0 Z = Even
parity0 (S k) = case parity0 k of
  Even => Odd
  Odd => Even
```

The first attempt to implement that for `Int`:

```
parity1: Int -> Parity
parity1 x = if mod x 2 == 0 then Even else Odd
```

This function is not total:

> Main.parity1 is possibly not total due to: Prelude.Interfaces.Int implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Integral

It makes sense because `mod` is not total for `Int`. (Although I'm not sure how I could know it in advance. The REPL shows that `mod` is total. Apparently, you can use a partial function to implement a total function of an interface? Strange.)

Next, I try to use `DivBy` view:

```
parity2: Int -> Parity
parity2 x with (divides x 2)
  parity2 ((2 * div) + rem) | (DivBy prf) =
    if rem == 0 then Even else Odd
```

This function works and is total, but the implementation is error-prone and doesn't scale to cases where we have multiple possible values. I'd like to assert that `rem` can only be 0 or 1. So I attempt to use `case` on `rem`:

```
parity3: Int -> Parity
parity3 x with (divides x 2)
  parity3 ((2 * div) + rem) | (DivBy prf) = case rem of
    0 => Even
    1 => Odd
```

This function also works but is not total. How can I use `prf` provided by `DivBy` to convince the compiler that it's total? How can I use this `prf` in general?

Would using `Integer` or some other type make this problem easier to solve?

And there is another very concerning thing. I tried to case-split on `prf` and discovered that the following function is total:

```
parity4: Int -> Parity
parity4 x with (divides x 2)
  parity4 ((2 * div) + rem) | (DivBy prf) impossible
```

Is that a bug? I can use this function to produce a runtime crash in a program that only contains total functions.

Comment: can you not `parity1 x = parity0 (cast (abs x))`?

Comment: No, `cast` is a lossy function, so I'm not sure why I would ever use it. In this case, `cast` would convert all negative numbers to 0, so the parity function would obviously be invalid.

Comment: sure, `cast` on its own would, but with `abs` you don't have that problem

Comment: There are two problems with the solution you propose. The first is that `cast` is lossy, so it can potentially produce a value that is not equal to the original value. For example, if `abs` doesn't work properly and returns a negative value, `cast` would turn it to 0 and I wouldn't get any error from the compiler. The second problem is that `abs` can indeed produce a negative value: if you pass `INT_MIN`  to it, it will return `INT_MIN` (because `abs(INT_MIN)` is unrepresentable). So both `cast` and `abs` are unsuitable if I want to make sure my function works correctly.